# establish_connection doesn't seem to support joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, multiple-databases, arel

I'm trying to move my User account and session data into a separate database so that we can eventually share it across multiple applications.

I've seen plenty of people online saying to use `establish_connection` to tell a model to connect to a different db, but I am unable to get this to work.

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  database: project_name_development

authentication:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  database: authentication
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :authentication
  has_one :person
end
```

**app/models/person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This much seems to be working:

```
> User.connection.instance_eval { @config[:database] }
=> "authentication"
> Person.connection.instance_eval { @config[:database] }
=> "project_name_development"
```

and I can query `User` in isolation:

```
> User.where(:admin => true)
=> [ ... lots of results .. ]
```

but as soon as I try to use `join` it breaks:

```
> User.joins(:person)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'authentication.people' doesn't exist: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `people` ON `people`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
```

ARel seems to be using the current database instead of getting the correct one through reflection.

I found [this very old bug report](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1902-establish_connection-does-not-support-joins) from almost two years ago about this problem, but I am almost certain it was regarding the old ARel syntax, and I really doubt the code examples would work anymore.

Is this even possible?

**Update**: made a little headway by doing this:

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN project_name.people ON project_name.people.user_id = authentication.users.id")
```

but that is really tedious, and one of the tables I'd like to join is polymorphic.

I tried adding:

```
set_table_name 'project_name.people'
```

but that returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems to me that Rails3 doesn't actually support multiple schemas. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've noticed the same issue when trying to port my 2.3 site to rails3. It seems Arel 2.0.6 maintains a connection to the original database and doesn't realise when the db is changed using establish_connection. Arel HEAD seems to be an improvement, but I'm noticing other errors. Bring on rails 3.0.4...

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Rails doesn't support that.

Comment: @karudzo the Rails API docs says that ActiveRecord supports using multiple DBs. If you can't use `join`, that doesn't qualify as 'support' in my book.

Comment: @AdamLassek, you can't use join across multiple databases because you can't use join across multiple databases - at all, in any platform imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about taking it out of the app layer and just replicating certain tables only with MySQL replication?

Comment: That may be necessary. Good suggestion.